# how to reduce file size Human Pose Estimation for mobile

Tags: tensorflow, opencv, pytorch, computer-vision, onnx

i use this file

Model(
name='LightWeight Human Pose Estimation (ONNX)', # https://github.com/Daniil-Osokin/lightweight-human-pose-estimation.pytorch
url='https://drive.google.com/uc?export=dowload&id=1--Ij_gIzCeNA488u5TA4FqWMMdxBqOji',
sha='5960f7aef233d75f8f4020be1fd911b2d93fbffc',
filename='onnx/models/lightweight_pose_estimation_201912.onnx')

for get Human Pose on Mobile !
I work on a frame and it works.
But I want to use it in real time
How can I reduce its size or is there a file that is lighter?

Comment: It looks like you want put a link to the pre-trained neural network weight, but it is hard to figure out how to reach the link in the Google Drive. Is there other way to share the file information differently (like file type and size)?  
Also have you asked in the issue section on the Github repository?

Comment: there *was* a much smaller model [here](https://github.com/ildoonet/tf-pose-estimation/blob/master/models/graph/mobilenet_thin/graph_freeze.pb), unfortunately it is gone ;( maybe you can find a cache of it ...